# Is there anyway to update nested array in firestore

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, object, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document in Firebase Firestore that is something like this.

```
 student: [
          {
            fname: "shiw",
            lname: "asdasd",
            stuid: "01",
            quizzing: [
              {
                answer: false,
                step: 1,
              },
              {
                answer: false,
                step: 2,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
```

And I want to update in field quzzing to like this

```
student: [
              {
                fname: "shiw",
                lname: "asdasd",
                stuid: "01",
                quizzing: [
                  {
                    answer: true,
                    step: 1,
                  },
                  {
                    answer: false,
                    step: 2,
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
```

I try to use update and arrayUnion but It overwritten all the document.

Comment: Get the entire document into a JS object. Modify it as you want. Then save it to Firestore.

Comment: I think that way is final solution because I want to change document like this but have 30+  docs